# Wireframe drawing application used by Microsoft for the MVC roadmap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drawing, wireframe

Can anyone tell me which application is used to draw the following image:

[image]

This image was taken from http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a screenshot from [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) to me.

I use it a lot myself, and it's a very good application to quickly draw up a mockup version of a program you are going to create, either for your own use, or to show to a client/customer before starting the actual development.

Answer (score 0):

We use Microsoft Visio for this purpose. It has Wireframing tools for exactly this purpose.